# Combining json objects from php-mysql query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, json

Is there a way to combine multiple json objects into 1 based on an identifier that is not the primary key?(PHP)

Using angularjs ng-repeat to display my data.  Since each record is being returned as individual json objects-  When I display this in an html table, I get 3 different rows repeating the id in each.

My goal is to have a header (being the id) then have 3 'sub rows' associated to that id.

```html
<tr ng-repeat-start="parent in parents | filter:search_query track by $index">
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-if="parent.expanded" ng-click="parent.expanded = false">-</button>
              <button class="btn btn-info" ng-if="!parent.expanded" ng-click="parent.expanded = true">+</button>
            </td>
            <td>{{parent.name}}</td>
     
          </tr>
          <tr ng-if="parent.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
            <td ng-repeat="parent in parent" colspan="3">{{parent.child}}</td>
          </tr>

</tr>
```

```js
JSON : 
0: Object
Parent:"Parent1"
Child :"Child1"

1: Object
Parent : "Parent1"
Child  : "Child2"

2: Object
Parent : "Parent1"
Child  : "Child3"
```

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: can you share the JSON?